# issue with laravel jetstream triggering profile image explorer twice (Livewire & AlpineJs)

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream, alpine.js

Good day Developers

I have this code that comes built in laravel jetstream:

input:file

```html
<input type="file" class="hidden"
       wire:model="photo"
       x-ref="photo"
       x-on:change="
            photoName = $refs.photo.files[0].name;
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                 photoPreview = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL($refs.photo.files[0]);
"/>
```

and explorer trigger:

```html
<x-jet-secondary-button class="mt-2 mr-2" type="button" x-on:click.prevent="$refs.photo.click()">
     {{ __('Select A New Photo') }}
</x-jet-secondary-button>
```

When I click on the button, it shows the explorer, the problem is that after selecting the image I want to upload, it reopens the file explorer again (Then I have to select the very same image for the second time) before it can successfully upload the image.

I tried searching the net for a solution but I'm really new to alpine and livewire I couldn't come to a solution.

If anyone can point out where the issue is, I'd appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem loading livewire twice, in my case, i was importing another js file in resources/app.js which is imported by the app's webpack-mix.js. And that additional file had a copy of resources/app.js, effectively loading Alpine twice and triggering events twice. After i removed the import, events fired only once.